# I am trying more advanced Discord bot status update and I started receiving "socket.send() raised exception." and non of the async commands work now

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

So this is part of my code, I can provide the entire thing if needed.

Previously my bot is all well when using this pretty standard status looping (the first bit). But since I tried the second version I started to receive

```
socket.send() raised exception.
```

And now running the bot makes all `async` commands unusable. Despite the commands are all correctly sent, nothing returns, and even the console doesn't show any errors for some reason... Does anyone understand why including client.change_presence(...) under on_ready() doesn't seem to work and why it conflicts with any other previously working commands?

````
status = cycle(['Vice-Captain of The Perkers', 'At your service...', 'AHIHIP Forever', 'Hey there!'])       #Status update


@tasks.loop(seconds=7.5)
async def change_status():
    await client.change_presence(activity=discord.Game(next(status)))


@client.event
async def on_ready():
    change_status.start()
    print("#G11 - The Perkers Vice-Captain Little Green reporting.")       
    time.sleep(0.75)
    print("What can I help with, sir?")```
````

```
import discord
import time
import datetime
import random
import math
import pytz
import dns
import os
import pymongo
from pymongo import MongoClient
from discord.ext import commands,tasks
from itertools import cycle
from discord.utils import get
from typing import List


client = commands.Bot(command_prefix='lg')
    

@tasks.loop(seconds=5)
async def status_change():
    while True:
        await client.wait_until_ready()
        await client.change_presence(status=discord.Status.idle, activity=discord.Game(name='Vice-Captain of The Perkers'))
        time.sleep(10)
        await client.change_presence(status=discord.Status.do_not_disturb, activity=discord.Game(name='At your service...'))
        time.sleep(10)
        await client.change_presence(status=discord.Status.online, activity=discord.Game(name='AHIHIP Forever!'))
        time.sleep(10)
    

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print("#G11 - The Perkers Vice-Captain Little Green reporting.")
    time.sleep(0.75)
    print("What can I help with, sir?")
    time.sleep(3)
    client.loop.create_task(status_change())
    

@client.command()       
async def hallo(ctx):
    await ctx.send('Hi!')
 

client.run('Token')
```

Comment: None of the commands are not working because there's a lot of blocking code here (mostly `time.sleep`), use `await asyncio.sleep(n)` instead.

Comment: What exception did `socket.send` raise? Posting a random, useless line of the whole traceback is pointless. Please *post the full traceback*. (Helpful article related to my previous comment: https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq.html#what-does-blocking-mean)

Comment: using asyncio does seem to fix it, thank you